# Intuition behind multiplying (or composing) permutations.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

I'm trying to grasp the intuition for permutations and their multiplication. So far this has been my intuitive understanding: A permutation is merely a shuffling of the symbols. Take for example $\sigma , \pi \in S_4$ given by,

$ \sigma = \left(\begin{matrix}1 & 2 & 3 &4 \\ 3 & 2& 1& 4 \end{matrix}\right)$ and $ \pi= 
 \left(\begin{matrix}1 & 2 & 3 &4 \\ 2 & 4& 1& 3 \end{matrix}\right)$

Now from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/534620/552998) answer, I could rewrite them as a $4-$tuple:

$\sigma = (3,2,1,4)$ and $\pi = (2,4,1,3)$ as permutations of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and so $ \pi \circ \sigma = (2,4,1,3) \circ (3,2,1,4) = (1,4,2,3) \tag{#}$

---

I understand how to *get* the result. I know how to multiply (or compose) two permutations.

> **My Question**: What happened in equation $\text{#}$ and what's going on intuitively? What shuffled around when composition happened? What does the result of product mean with respect to $\pi$ and $\sigma$?

Answer (score 1):

We can formulate the composition rule of permutations given in the form
\begin{align*}
\pi \circ \sigma = (2,4,1,3) \circ (3,2,1,4) = (1,4,2,3)
\end{align*}
as

> - Select the items of the left-hand permutation $\pi$ in the order given by the items  of the right-hand permutation $\sigma$.

In the current example we have the order of the items of the right-hand permutation $\sigma$ as

\begin{align*}
\sigma=(3,2,1,4) \to \text{third, second, first and fourth item of }\pi
\end{align*}

resulting in

$$\color{blue}{\pi\circ\sigma=(1,4,2,3)}$$

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that it happens what the definition says it should happen: if you say that $f=(f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4)$ is the function such that $f(i)=f_i$, and if you say that $\pi\circ \sigma$ is the function such that $(\pi\circ \sigma)(i)=\pi(\sigma(i))$, then the representation of $\pi\circ\sigma$ will be given by $(\pi\circ\sigma)_i=\pi_{\sigma_i}$.

Of course, you should be careful whe you use this the one-line notation because you are using essentially the same notation as the very common [cycle notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Cycle_notation).

Comment: Okay, but I know it's a composition of two functions. I have made that clear in the question to prevent confusion. What I'm looking for is intuition taking into consideration that they're permutations and they're supposed to be moving symbols around.

Comment: I'm also not using the cycle notation, it does not have commas. But I mentioned it's a tuple to be safe, already in my question.

Comment: "Moving things around" is exactly what a bijective function from a set to itself (that is a permutation)  does. Multiplying permutations is "do one, then the other". That is composition of functions.